# Stand and Pop Filter for Samson Go Mic

Tags: microphone, filter, pop, microphone-stand

Which Mic stand and Pop Filter is best for Samson Go Mic?

Comment: Without more detail this question isn't meaningfully answerable.  Mic stands and pop filters are more about the situation you are using the mic in than the type of mic and you haven't provided any of that detail.  The short answer is what Tetsujin said though unless you have some special environmental needs.

Comment: @AJHenderson I think you misunderstood the Samson Go Mic. It's a USB Mic.

Comment: that really doesn't matter.  You still pick a mic stand and pop filter based on the conditions it needs to work in.  The stand based on how you need to be able to position it and the pop filter based on what kind of filtering it will need to do (is there wind, how many people speaking, etc).  There are other possible factors too, but the main point is there is nothing in this question that lets it be meaningfully answered other than "pick one".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has a standard Euro thread, so it will go on any mic stand.

[image]

One of the best pop shields is a simple diffuser you can make at home.
You can buy these ready-made & quite neat-looking, with a proper clip...

[image]

...but the principle is the same.
Stretch a pair of tights [ladies' hose] over a coat hanger.

It can be as rough as you like...

[image]

or as neat...

[image]

The result is the same.